# Alguém conhece uma biblioteca que calcula integral e derivadas em java

Tags: java, matemática

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece uma biblioteca que calcula integral e derivadas em java.

Comment: A pergunta é vaga. Devias acrescentar: de forma numérica (dado que de forma simbólica não há).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que [esta resposta do stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886145/is-there-a-method-in-java-that-can-do-integration) responda tua pergunta.

Das bibliotecas descritas na resposta a mais relevante (na minha opinião) é [Commons Math Libray](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html#a4.4%5FIntegration) que é manutenida pela Apache.

Comment: Você postou o link da pergunta, e não de uma das respostas.

Comment: Existem 4 respostas na pergunta e as 2 primeiras são relevantes.